# How to override css from style of div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div and having some class and style. I want to override or change my style. How to put this in to css.

Here is my div which i get from inspect element.

```
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;">
```

I want my `text-align:right` How to achieve this.

Comment: use `!important`

Comment: @sweaver2112 Do i need to write a separate css class ?

Comment: make a unique class or ID name so that it won't affect the other CSS.

Comment: @AravindS Can I write in this classs `x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn`

Comment: @David you can write `div.x-grid-cell-inner.x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn` , but make sure it won't affect other elements.

Comment: @sweaver2112 Using `!important` is just asking for trouble. Use it once, and soon you'll realize you'll start having it everywhere but it's really not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the that by using the [`!important exception`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) with those classes. Please keep in mind that you have to use a new `class` or `id` if you do not want the new style to affect all the elements having these classes:

```css
.x-grid-cell-inner.x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn{
  text-align:right !important;
}
```

```html
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn" style="text-align:left;">Test Container</div>
```

Comment: downvoting; `!important` should be used as a last resort because it's the highest priority. A simple solution could be to give the div an ID and just add a simple rule with `#ID { text-align: left }`

Comment: You should take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: @DanyKhalife, OP's requirement was to use those classes....that is enough to be the highest priority.....

Comment: I don't agree. Giving someone a cheap fix without explaining the caveats isn't helpful for them. If the OP wants to use classes only, then add another class as your default answer

Comment: @DanyKhalife, I think you are better in position than OP in the question.....Better provide an answer and explain that to OP to accept that as an answer....

Answer (score 1):

`div.x-grid-cell-inner.x-grid-cell-inner-treecolumn {text-align:right !important; }`

make sure it won't affect your other elements

Comment: downvoting for the same reason mentioned above

Comment: @DanyKhalife - i already mentioned it in my comments above to use the unique ID. since the user wants to try css with the class name, that is the reason why given the answer with class.